# Search text in firefox dev tools

Tags: html, firefox, search

I am trying to search for text in an html file via firefox dev tools. When I do a search via `control + F`, the search only identifies html/css elements(e.g. id's, classes, body, etc..). I would like to search for actual text in html element. For example, how can I search for the text "example" in `<li>example</li>`?

Comment: Open you web page , then press `Ctrl+U`  then find you code by `Ctrl+F`.

Comment: @MohitGupta That worked. Thank you